# Integrate pentaho di with web application

Tags: java, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have to develop a java interface in my application, where business user can run jobs/transformations. I need a guideline, how it is possible? 
P.S: I'm naive. I don't know much about Pentaho.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is too broad to be answered in an effective way, please narrow down your request after some research and some effort. Please take some time to read the [help] pages, take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Also please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: You supply almost nothing about the environment and no details, so it's impossible to give you an answer that you could just implement without knowing anything about Pentaho. Read the manuals, do the tutorials, collect the requirements. Then if you have a specific question there's a much better chance of someone here being able to answer.

Comment: The question is too broad because the user is new in Pentaho. Help him to narrow down his question and provide a example.

Answer (score 2):

The interface exists and shipped with your PDI distribution. It is called `pan.sh` for job and `kitchen.sh` for transformations. User guide is here: https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/7.0/0L0/0Y0/070.

If your user do not fancy linux shell, there is a nice web app called `Carte`, you launch it on a server (specifying a port), then you can launch/watch/stop/restart job+transformations from the browser. Doc is here: https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Carte+User+Documentation, and except maybe the first test, there is nothing simpler to use.

If foe some reason, you need a java interface, you'll find it in the Chapter 22 of the book Pentaho Kettle Solutions: Building Open Source ETL Solutions with Pentaho Data Integration. With working examples.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlainD for referring me this book. I'll definitely go through it. Yeah i know Pentaho does have an interface but our client wants to run jobs and transformations on their own. The only way we can facilitate them is by providing an interface in application.

Comment: Carte IS such a interface to run and monitor job and transformation, with simple clicks. It is web based, so controlled with a few urls. If your client insist to have they own application, you may have better to write a nice set of buttons that will issue `url.openConnection()` to start and stop job&trans. With a `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()))` you will get feedback data to display on the screen.

Comment: An interesting possibility is to use the PDI logging system : the progress of the run (rows read/written/rejected/with errors,...) is written in a database. And that database can be read by an independent java app. An example of this achitecture is here : github.com/alaindebecker/ETL-pilot